How to insert to table B and update a column in table A with common ID in Spring Batch?
I have 2 tables tableA(source) and tableB(destination) and a Spring Batch process which reads records from tableA and insert it into tableB. Once a record is inserted into tableB, I need to update column picked_state from null to PICKED in tableA. Both tables has a common column named as txn_ref_no in TableA and transaction_id in tableB.
I have a Spring Batch setup ready which takes and inserts records to tableB.
I am using JdbcPagingItemReader to read records and write with JdbcBatchItemWriter.
How to implement the setup to update picked_state to this? I have just started using Spring Batch.
One approach I can think of is to add a tasklet after the insert and execute SQL:
UPDATE tableA SET picked_state = 'PICKED' WHERE txn_ref_no IN (SELECT transaction_id FROM tableB)

But here,
WHERE txn_ref_no IN (SELECT transaction_id FROM tableB)

Is not efficient. What is the right way to solve this?

I'd go with merge:
merge into tablea a
  using tableb b
  on (a.txn_ref_no = b.transaction_id)
when matched then 
  update set a.picked_state = 'PICKED';

or exists:
update tablea a set
  a.picked_state = 'PICKED'
where exists (select null
              from tableb b
              where b.transaction_id = a.txn_ref_no
             );


Make sure that both txn_ref_no and transaction_id are indexed. Regularly collect statistics.
